# AWS Step Function: state A pass lambda output to state B

Tags: aws-step-functions

My AWS lambda function `check-version-lambda` returns
`{"latest": "yes"}` or `{"latest": "no"}`.

I have the AWS step function below, to pass above result to next state.

The next state `process_version` is a choice state, how do I retrieve the input inside `Choices`? What to fill in for `<???>`?

```
  {
      "StartAt": "check_version",
      "States": {
        "check_version": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000:function:check-version-lambda",
          "OutputPath": "$.latest",
          "Next": "process_version"
        },
        "process_version": {
          "Type": "Choice",
          "Choices": [
            {
              "Variable": "<???>",
              "StringEquals": "yes",
              "Next": "next_state"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "<???>",
              "StringEquals": "no",
              "Next": "next_state"
            }
          ],
          "Default": "next_state"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "check_version" state, you can use

```
"ResultPath": "$.result",
"OutputPath": "$.result",
```

to explicitly configure the step function to put the result of the lambda (e.g. `{"latest": "yes"}`) into the `result` property of the input object. `OutputPath` tells the step function to only select that result as state output and hand it over to the next state.

In your "process_version" state, you should then be able to use:

```
"Variable": "$.result.latest",
"StringEquals": "yes",
"Next": ...
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html